# Can't update image to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update my database by inserting a new picture.
There is no error when i'm running the code, but the picture is not going into the database. Below is my code:

```html
<?php
    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
    require_once 'dbcon.php';
    
    if(isset($_GET['edit_id']) && !empty($_GET['edit_id']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
        $stmt_edit = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT audit_id, audit_id, descr, correction, status FROM correction WHERE correction_id =:cid');
        $stmt_edit->execute(array(':cid'=>$id));
        $edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        extract($edit_row);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: correction.php");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['btn_save_updates']))
    {
        $audit_id = $_POST['audit_id'];
        $descr = $_POST['descr']; 
        $status = $_POST['status'];      
        $imgFile = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        if($imgFile)
        {
            $upload_dir = 'images/';
            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
            $userprofile = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions))
            {           
                if($imgSize < 5000000)
                {
                    unlink($upload_dir.$edit_row['correction']);
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$correction);
                }
                else
                {
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, Your File Is Too Large To Upload. It Should Be Less Than 5MB.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF Extension Files Are Allowed.";      
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $correction = $edit_row['correction'];
        }
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE correction SET correction_id=:cid, audit_id=:aid, descr=:descr, correction=:pic, status=:stat WHERE correction_id=:cid');
            $stmt->bindParam(':aid',$audit_id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':descr',$descr);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pic',$correction);
            $stmt->bindParam(':stat',$status);
            $stmt->bindParam(':cid',$id);
                
            if($stmt->execute()){
                ?>
                <script>
                alert('Successfully Updated...');
                window.location.href='correction.php';
                </script>
                <?php
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry. Could Not Be Updated!";
            }
        }           
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset =  "UTF-8">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Audit Management System</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav class  = "navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "navbar-header">
                <a class = "navbar-brand">Audit Management System</a>
            </div>
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="auditee_home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="schedule_v.php">Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="generate.php">Generate Report</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="correction.php">Correction</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <div class = "col-md-12 well">
            <a class = "btn btn-success" href = "correction.php"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> Back</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div class = "alert alert-warning">Correction</div>
            <div class = "row"> 
                <div class = "col-md-2 ">
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-2">
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <?php
                        $correction_id=$_GET['edit_id'];
                        $acc_query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `correction` WHERE correction_id = '$_REQUEST[edit_id]'") or die(mysqli_error());
                        $acc_fetch = $acc_query->fetch_array();
                    ?>
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="correction_id" value="<?php echo $correction_id; ?>">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>Audit ID</label>
                            <input name="audit_id" id = "audit_id" type = "text" value = "<?php echo $acc_fetch['audit_id']?>" class = "form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <input name="descr" type = "text" id = "descr" type = "text" value= "<?php echo $acc_fetch['descr']?>" class = "form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>Correction</label>
                            <input name="image" type = "file" class = "input-group" accept="image/*" />
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>Status</label>
                            <input name="status" type = "text" id = "descr" type = "text" value= "<?php echo $acc_fetch['status']?>" class = "form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
                        </div>

                        <div id = "loading">
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <button type="submit" name="btn_save_updates" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>&nbsp; Save</button>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="home.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

any kind of help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

seems like number of parameters are not matching in prepare statement.

```
<?php
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE correction SET correction_id=:cid, audit_id=:aid, descr=:descr, correction=:pic, status=:stat WHERE correction_id=:cid2');
$stmt->bindParam(':cid',$id);
$stmt->bindParam(':aid',$audit_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':descr',$descr);
$stmt->bindParam(':pic',$correction);
$stmt->bindParam(':stat',$status);
$stmt->bindParam(':cid2',$id);
```

Comment: i've changed my code according to your suggestion, but the image is still not in the database